# How to avoid 'require is undefined' error on the frontend when compiling 3rd party libraries

Tags: javascript, gulp, frontend

I'm using GulpJS to compile all the 3rd party libraries that my app needs (for the frontend). I install these libraries via NPM, and use Gulp to concatenate and compile them into a single 'vendor' JS file. They get compiled correctly, but when I load the app in the browser, I get a "require is not defined" error. This is because some of the 3rd party libraries are using the 'require' syntax that is usually used in a node server environment. This pattern is getting popular on the frontend, however, I am not sure the best way to resolve this problem for my app.

From reading online, it seems like a gulp browserify plugin could be used, or requireJS. I currently don't have either installed. I tried the gulp browserify method but abandoned it as things were getting complex (I am not against trying this again if it is the recommended method). What is odd to me is that in the past, this was never a problem with the same 3rd party libraries. It seems like our app is behind the times.

Expected: all 3rd party libraries compile into a single file and the browser loads it fine.
Actual: all 3rd party libraries get compiled into a single file, but that file uses the 'require' syntax and therefore throws an error in the browser when the app tries to load.

Comment: Use webpack or another bundler of your choice.

Comment: @connexo I am using GulpJS to bundle the libraries into a single file - the problem is that some of these libraries use the `require` syntax which the browser cant handle. I'm wondering if there is a way to resolve this without using webpack/browserify/requireJS, or if using one of those options is absolutely necessary.